# view attached in the fragment showing null id after after another activity on top of it is removed from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle

I have a fragment on top of which i am calling a start-activity-for-result.When the activity is finished and result is returned to the activity linked with fragment at that point i want to do some user-interface operation but all the id of the views have become null in the fragment.

Comment: Also post your code

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Got the solution, i had to save the state of the fragment and on activity created method restore it.